# Leading zeros on Stripe Exp_Month

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, php-carbon

Using the Stripe API I'm trying to show the credit cards expiration date.

I use `exp_month` to grab the month & and it works fine.

```
{{ $stripeCustomer->sources->data[0]->exp_month }}
```

My issue is there is no leading zero when I grab the month.
Output looks like this: June = 6. I want June to = 06

I tried using Carbon like this:

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($stripeCustomer->sources->data[0]->exp_month)->format('m') }}
```

but the data[0] throws the error:

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2) at position 0
>   (2): Unexpected character

So if I remove the `data[0]`

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($stripeCustomer->sources->exp_month)->format('m') }}
```

I get the leading 0, but I get the output of 08.. which is the current month at the time of this question.

---

How can I make this work so I get the leading zero and correct month?

Comment: Could you just left pad the value with leading 0s up to 2 characters? Would handle 1-9 and ignore 10-12.

Comment: You can use `sprintf("%'02d", $stripeCustomer->sources->data[0]->exp_month);`

Comment: @manuerumx that worked great. Please change to an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
sprintf("%'02d", $stripeCustomer->sources->data[0]->exp_month);
```

Change the 2 if you need more zeros.